# Why can't I use $this for my method but my property?

Tags: php, object, methods, this

I am starting out with object oriented PHP, but I'm running in issues using `$this`

That's my current code:

```
class Computer {
    public $CPU = "<br> Die CPU <br>";

    public function starten() {
        echo "<br> Computer ist gestartet. <br>";
    }

    public function herunterfahren(&$sekunden = 20) {
        echo "Der PC wird in $sekunden Sekunden heruntergefahren.";
    }

    public function beides() {
        echo "Die CPU Methode klatsch: " . $this->CPU . " raus, beim herunterfahren sieht es anders aus: " . $this->herunterfahren();
    }
}

$meinComputer = new Computer();

$meinComputer->starten();

echo $meinComputer->CPU;

$meinComputer->CPU = "3GHz.";

echo $meinComputer->CPU;
echo "<br><br>";
$meinComputer->herunterfahren();
echo "<br><br>";
$dauer = 12;
$meinComputer->herunterfahren($dauer);

echo "<br><br><br><br>";
$meinComputer->beides();
```

The output works well, but `$meinComputer->beides();` does not show the  `$this->herunterfahren();` part.  The output is:

Der PC wird in 20 Sekunden heruntergefahren.Die CPU Methode klatsch: 3GHz. raus, beim herunterfahren sieht es anders aus:

instead of:

Der PC wird in 20 Sekunden heruntergefahren.Die CPU Methode klatsch: 3GHz. raus, beim herunterfahren sieht es anders aus: Der PC wird in 20 Sekunden heruntergefahren.

When I enter a parameter for `$sekunden` like that: 
public function beides() {

echo "Die CPU Methode klatsch: " . $this->CPU . " raus, beim herunterfahren sieht es anders aus: " . $this->herunterfahren(10);
          }

it does not show anything, after running: `$meinComputer->beides();`

I don't get, why it can't output that part of the code..

Comment: `&` before variable means `passing by reference`. So any variable you pass to this method you change the value if the code inside the method change this variable value. So, as you are using OOP and you do nothing with `$sekunden`, makes no sense to use `&$sekunden`. Just remove the `&` before `$sekunden`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the method

```
$this->herunterfahren()
```

prints a text with some parameter, it doesn't return anything.. so when it's evaluated in this line:

```
echo "Die CPU M..: " . $this->CPU . " raus, be... " . $this->herunterfahren();
```

the method runs right away printing the text below
without returning any value the current echo function can use

```
"Der PC wird in $sekunden(value) Sekunden heruntergefahren"
```

to fix that use a `return` instead of `echo` in the `herunterfahren` method like so:

```php
public function herunterfahren(&$sekunden = 20) {
        return "Der PC wird in $sekunden Sekunden heruntergefahren.";}
```

after doing that you need to take care of this part :

```
echo $meinComputer->herunterfahren();
```